# PHP Merging Row with same value (more than one column)

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table:

```
    Material Number | BPM Number | STTPP Number | Qty 

    A | 123 | 1231 | 100
    A | 123 | 1232 | 200
    B | 234 | 2341 | 100
    B | 234 | 2342 | 100
    C | 432 | 4321 | 100
    D | 567 | 5671 | 100
    D | 567 | 5672 | 600
    D | 568 | 5681 | 300
    D | 568 | 5682 | 200
    D | 598 | 5981 | 100
    D | 598 | 5672 | 90
```

and trying to display it look like this :

```
    Material Number | BPM Number | STTPP Number | Qty 

    A | 123 | 1231 | 100
      |     | 1232 | 200
    B | 234 | 2341 | 100
      |     | 2342 | 100
    C | 432 | 4321 | 100
    D | 567 | 5671 | 100
      |     | 5672 | 600
      | 568 | 5681 | 300
      |     | 5682 | 200
      | 598 | 5981 | 100
      |     | 5672 | 90
```

Searching everywhere but I just found that they only merge 1st column... 
this is what I've done so far:

```
    <?php
        $query="SELECT * FROM sttpp_item_list order by material_code";
        $proses=mysql_query($query);
        $i=0; 
        while($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($proses))
        {
           $row[$i]=$data;
           $i++;
        }
        foreach($row as $cell)
        {
           if(isset($total[$cell['material_code']]['quantity_dely'])) 
           { 
               $total[$cell['material_code']]['quantity_dely']++; 
           }
           else
           {
               $total[$cell['material_code']]['quantity_dely']=1; 
           }    
         }
         echo "<table border=\"1\"> 
         <tr> 
             <th>Material Number</th> 
             <th>BPM Number</th> 
             <th>STTPP Number</th>  
             <th>STTPP Number</th> 
         </tr>";
         $n=count($row);
         $cekmaterial_code="";
         for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++)
         {
             $cell=$row[$i];
             echo '<tr>';
             if($cekmaterial_code!=$cell['material_code'])
             {
                 echo '<td' .($total[$cell['material_code']] 
                 'quantity_dely']>1?' rowspan="' .
                 ($total[$cell['material_code']]['quantity_dely']).'">':'>') 
                 .$cell['material_code'].'</td>';
                 $cekmaterial_code=$cell['material_code'];
              }
              echo "<td>$cell[bpm_number]</td><td>$cell[quantity_dely]
              </td>";
              echo "</tr>";
              }
              echo "</table>";
       ?>
```

This code result:

Material Number | BPM Number | STTPP Number | Qty

```
    A | 123 | 1231 | 100
      | 123 | 1232 | 200
    B | 234 | 2341 | 100
      | 234 | 2342 | 100
    C | 432 | 4321 | 100
    D | 567 | 5671 | 100
      | 567 | 5672 | 600
      | 568 | 5681 | 300
      | 568 | 5682 | 200
      | 598 | 5981 | 100
      | 598 | 5672 | 90
```

Any suggestion? please Help...

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not complete, but I will try to solve. You just have to do checking on `$cell['bpm_number']` like you do on `$cell['material_code']`.

```
$cekmaterial_code = "";
$bpm_number = "";
for (...) {
...
  if ($bpm_number !== $cell['bpm_number'])
    $bpm_number = $cell['bpm_number'];
    echo "<td>$cell[bpm_number]</td><td>$cell[quantity_dely</td>";
  } else {
    echo "<td></td><td>$cell[quantity_dely]</td>";
  }
..
}
```

Comment: interesting but it doesn't count how much the row to span?